# prestashop Error on every page other then homepage

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I got error on each category page. like if I click on any product from home page its showing me below error. Any product. Please help someone thanks.

---

[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

```
Db->executeS() must be used only with select, show, explain or describe queries
at line 470 in file classes/db/Db.php

464.            //print_r($sql);exit;
465.        // This method must be used only with queries which display results
466.        if (!preg_match('#^\s*\(?\s*(select|show|explain|describe|desc)\s#i', $sql))
467.        {
468.            if (defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_') && _PS_MODE_DEV_)
469.                throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException('Db->executeS() must be used only with select, show, explain or describe queries');
470.            return $this->execute($sql, $use_cache);
471.        }
472. 
473.        $this->result = false;
474.        $this->last_query = $sql;
DbCore->executeS - [line 130 - modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.php] - [1 Arguments]
BlockViewed->hookRightColumn - [line 192 - modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.php] - [1 Arguments]
BlockViewed->hookLeftColumn - [line 423 - classes/Hook.php] - [1 Arguments]
HookCore::exec - [line 427 - classes/controller/FrontController.php] - [1 Arguments]
FrontControllerCore->initContent - [line 84 - override/classes/controller/FrontController.php] - [0 Argument]
FrontController->initContent - [line 173 - controllers/front/ProductController.php] - [0 Argument]
ProductControllerCore->initContent - [line 7 - override/controllers/front/ProductController.php] - [0 Argument]
ProductController->initContent - [line 167 - classes/controller/Controller.php] - [0 Argument]
ControllerCore->run - [line 349 - classes/Dispatcher.php] - [0 Argument]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 28 - index.php] - [0 Argument]
```

Thanks,
Aj!

Comment: well, care to explain if you have modified classes/db/Db.php? are you doing a fresh install, has your install failed? which version you've got?

Answer (score 0):

The error is at your modules/blockviewed/blockviewed.php at line 130 . You are using executeS function on a such a query which is not SELECT. check that file on line 130 and share the code, so i can see the code.

Thanks